# c++ returning a list of object pointers read from file

Tags: c++, list

I've this member function which returns a list of object pointers

```
list<Product*> Product::loadProducsts(){
    ifstream file;
    Product temp;
    list<Product*> products;
    file.open("cigarettes.dat", ios::binary);
    if(file.is_open()){
        file.seekg(0, ios::end);
        int size=(int) file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        while(file.tellg()<size){
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&temp), sizeof(temp));
            Product* r = new Product;
            r=&temp;
            products.push_front(r);
        }
    }
    file.close();

    return products;
}
```

into my main function i call this function and then I would like to print some value of object

```
......
list<Product*> s;
......
s=p.loadProducsts();
    for(list<Product*>::iterator iter = s.begin(),end = s.end(); iter!=end; ++iter){

        cout << (*iter)->getModel();
    }
```

Now I can't see nothing on console and I've this error

> *Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/signal/../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c"*

and during execution some times it give me this warning:

> *can't find linker symbol for virtual table for 'Product' value*

I think that it is a problem about free memory when execution of main is ending.
Any suggestions?

Comment: No, those are all compile/linker errors. Suggests you're probably not building something correctly.

Comment: Even after you've fixed your linking problem, your code is still very buggy. You're allocating a new `Product` on the heap, only to overwrite the pointer with the address of the local `temp` variable (causing the just allocated memory to be a leak), and then push that pointer to the local object onto the list (causing that pointer to be dangling as soon as you return). Why aren't you using value semantics? (The reading with `reinterpret_cast` looks also fishy, but without knowing the definition of `Product` there is no way to say if it is actually an error, or just a bad idea)

Comment: Wait, I have to correct myself: The last error message tells me that `Product` has virtual member functions, and therefore your reading code is erroneous.

Comment: `Product` hasn't any virtual member function, I think that when I try to destory all instance of objcet something goes wrong

Comment: If I run this code not in debug mode I haven't any errors, but `cout << (*iter)->getModel();` not works @celtschk

Answer (score -1):

Even aside from the compilation issues, there are a couple of things here: Firstly, you're creating on `Product` instance on the *stack* in your function. You then create a *heap* based `Product` here:

```
Product* r = new Product;
```

but then you throw away (leak) the object by replacing the pointer with the address of your *stack* based variable:

```
r=&temp;
```

so you end up with a collection of the same pointer repeated numerous times and lots of leaked heap objects.

Secondly, rather than just force-casting a lot of binary data into your object, it would be better to ensure that your `Product` object properly serialises and deserialises itself so you can simply write:

```
Product r;
file >> r;
products.push_front(r);
```

within your loop. Notice also how I've used objects by value rather than raw pointers? If you have good copy semantics and your object is not overly large, the efficiency loss will more than be compensated for by the reduction in fragility. If pointers are important to you, try to use a smart pointer to ensure you minimise the chance of leaks. Good luck!

Comment: First of all I should open a file in binary mode and with the low knowledge in my mind your solution `file >> r` isn't the correct way. Then, this function is a member function into `Product` class and I call it from `main` and into it I would extract objects from list and manipulate them. Well, if I create a `list<Product>` instead of `list<Product*>` into `main` may be instances of objects are corrupted because function is terminated to return list outside of `main`

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no restriction to prevent streaming binary data into an object provided you have overriden the streaming operators correctly. Personally I would seperate the file reading process to a manager class and leave only the specific `Product` deserialisation in the class itself. It's a reasonably common model, but of course, it's your decision. _"may be instances of objects are corrupted because function is terminated to return list outside of main"_ - sorry, I'm afraid I don't know what this means.

Comment: The problem is this: into Product class I've a sting field, and string isn't serializable into binary file. So this misunderstanding generate all other inconvenience